# Dirac delta distribution and supremum

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have asked the same question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448559/dirac-delta-distribution-and-supremum). 
My doubt follows from this [paper](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/epdf/10.1287/opre.51.4.543.16101) pg. 546. The context is they find the lagrangian function and the primal variable is the set of all density functions.
To make the question more precise, I am considering different notations. 
Consider the problem $$\sup_{p} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \big(\mathbb{1}(ax \leq b) - x^TMx \big) p(x)dx, $$
where $1(\cdot)$ is the indicator function and $M$ is the Lagrange dual variable. I don't think the indicator function has any role in the following statements. 
In the paper, two cases are considered. If $\big(\mathbb{1}(ax \leq b) - x^TMx \big) \leq 0$, then the problem has value $0$. (I think this is because we fix a  [dirac delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) at the point $0$).
If $\big(\mathbb{1}(ax \leq b) - x^TMx \big) \geq 0$, then the value is $+\infty$. I am not sure about this case; what distribution are we fixing here? Is it the dirac delta distribution? If so, then are we saying that the distribution  takes the value   $+\infty$ when  $\big(\mathbb{1}(ax \leq b) - x^TMx \big) = +\infty$ ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!